# Obtain MAC address from IP address

Tags: python, python-3.x, mac-address

I am just learning python 3.6.4 and I'm trying to get this code to work...

I have a list of ip addresses (on my LAN) and I need to obtain the associated mac address for each ip in the list.

When I run the code I get this error:

> ip_addresses_as_bytes = str.encode(ip_addresses) TypeError: descriptor
>   'encode' requires a 'str' object but received a 'list'

I can't figure out how to convert the individual list items to bytes.

```
import subprocess
import re

def get_mac_addresses(ip_addresses):

            for ip_address in ip_addresses:
                subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c 1", ip_address], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

            proc = subprocess.Popen("arp -a", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

            data = proc.communicate()[0]

            results = []

            ip_address_as_bytes = str.encode(ip_address)
            type(ip_address_as_bytes)  # ensure it is byte representation

            ip_addresses_as_bytes = str.encode(ip_addresses)
            type(ip_addresses_as_bytes)

            for ip_address_as_bytes in ip_addresses_as_bytes[:]:
                if ip_address_as_bytes in data:

                    ip_data = data[data.find(ip_address_as_bytes):]

                    mac = re.search(r"(([a-f\d]{1,2}:){5}[a-f\d]{1,2})", ip_data)

                    if mac is None:
                        mac = re.search(r"(([a-f\d]{1,2}-){5}[a-f\d]{1,2})", ip_data)

                    if mac is not None:
                        mac = mac.groups()[0].replace('-', ':').upper()

                    else:
                        mac = '00:00:00:00:00:00'

                    ip_addresses = ip_addresses_as_bytes.decode()
                    type(ip_addresses)  # ensure it is string representation

                    ip_address = ip_address_as_bytes.decode()
                    type(ip_address)  # ensure it is string representation

                    ip_addresses.remove(ip_address)

                    results += [[ip_address, mac]]

                return results
```

I appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: You are passin a list of IP addresses but need to pass only one.  Use `ip_addresses[0]` to pass the first one or use a loop if you want each one to be encoded

Comment: If you don't want to parse those complicated outputs, try that: [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
ip_addresses_as_bytes = str.encode(ip_addresses)
```

`ip_addresses` is a list, encode expects a string.

Use a loop:

```
ip_addresses_as_bytes = []
for ip_addresse in ip_addresses:
    ip_addresses_as_bytes.append(str.encode(ip_addresses))
```